Load data from xml file into List<> using C# MAUI
I am building a MAUI project in VS2022 using C#.
I am trying to load data from an xml file:
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <Event>
        <ETitle>Norwegian Fjords Cruise</ETitle>
        <EStartDate>03/05/2025 08:00:00</EStartDate>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <ETitle>Christmas Day</ETitle>
        <EStartDate>25/012/2024 08:00:00</EStartDate>
    </Event>
</root>

Into a List<> with structure:
public class Event
{
    public required string ETitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime EStartDate { get; set; }
}

So List.
Currently, my code to try and do this is
readonly string filepath = "EventsList.xml";
public DestCV()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<Event>? Events = [];
    XmlSerializer serializer = new(Events.GetType());
    try
    {
        FileStream fs2 = new(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        Events = serializer.Deserialize(fs2) as List<Event>;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    pckr.ItemsSource = Events;
    pckr.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

It builds without error or warning.
When I Debug it in Windows it crashes at the line FileStream fs2 = new(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read); (which you will notice is in a try catch block), and returns the App.g.i.cs file with the following highlighted
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif

I know I am doing something wrong but the error "report" is not really helping me to identify what.  Any advice is appreciated.

seems you aren't pointing to the correct full path of EventsList.xml

Change your exception and see what is the actual issue…. catch (Exception ex)
{
// You can log the error or show it in a message box during debugging
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

When it breaks you need to examine the Exception e to see what the root cause is.  This is basic C# debugging

Can you tell me which platform you are using, and where your xml files are placed ？

Please try the following solution.
It shows how to deserialize correctly your XML file into a List<Event>.
Classes and their properties should be decorated to provide mapping with an XML file and its XML elements.
c#
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\Temp\EventsList.xml";
    Events events;
    
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Events));

    using (Stream reader = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        events = (Events)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(events);
}

[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Events
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Event")]
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Event")]
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement("ETitle")]
    public string ETitle { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("EStartDate")]
    public string EStartDate { get; set; }
}


Thank you so much, really sorted things out for me, is there any chance you could point me in the direction of where this comes from.  I have been using C# for a little while and have never come across the decoration before.

Check it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=net-8.0

And here: (1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization, (2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

You unmarked the answer. What happened?

I took your sample from the original question and provided a perfectly working solution. If you are getting an exception it means your real life XML and classes are somewhat different...
